# a trouble about UITableFooterView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, table-footer

After add a footerview to the tableview, if the table has one cell only , the footer displays a little high just at the bottom of the cell. How to make it display at the foot of the tableview no matter how many cells the table has?

Comment: the tablefooterview's location is depend on how many section/cell and your cell's height,if you want the footerview always at the foot of the tableview, i think only custom view can help you.

Comment: that does not work. if i add a custom view to the tableview at the same time there are many cells in the table ,and the customview will never display below the last cell.

Answer (score 0):

footerView is just the background, add a view that you really want, just like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let footerView = UIView.init()
    footerView.backgroundColor = .red

    // footerView is just the background, add a view that you really want
    let subView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 100 - 40))
    subView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    footerView.addSubview(subView)

    return footerView
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Pleas post answers in the appropriate language.

Comment: i return a label  in this way , does not work . the footer displays always below the last cell . if the first cell is also the last , the footer displays a little high. add subviews to footer can not  change its position.

Comment: return a view which has a label.   you can't change the 'return view's frame, but you can change the label's position

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to set view on tableFooterView and its working fine.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewTableFooterView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tblView.tableFooterView = _viewTableFooterView;
    _tblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [_tblView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Check code and let me know if its not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the footer view that you are adding is the footer of the content you are displaying inside the `UITableView`. That being said there is a way to get the output you want. What you can do is drag a `UIView` below the `UITableViewCell` added in the storyboard for it to appear as a footer.

Setup constraints for the `UILabel` or anything you want to show inside with respect to this view, what I mean is don't add fixed height constraints otherwise you will get annoying layout breaking warnings. 
Make a duplicate of this footer view and add it to the bottom your `UITableView` and add a fixed height for it to make it as a copy of the footer view you added inside the `UITableView`. Sort of like this:

[image]

Now, create an outlet for this height constraint of the footer view into your `UIViewController`.

Now in your `viewDidLoad` what you can do is check if the height of the `UITableView` after adding the cells is less than screen bounds and proceed accordingly, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //dont show footer view if cells are within screen bounds
    if (numberOfCells * cellHeight < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height){

        UIView *footerView = mainTableView.tableFooterView;

        CGRect tempFrame = footerView.frame;

        tempFrame.size.height = 0.0f;

        footerView.frame = tempFrame;

        mainTableView.tableFooterView = footerView;

    }else{

        //dont show footerview below table view if cells are outside screen bounds
        [footerHeightConstraint setConstant:0.0f];
    }

}
```

**Note:** I have missed an edge case related to height like the product of rows * height coming to be equal or just less than screen bounds, so you'll have to have a look at that.

Comment: good idea.But that just means UITablefooterview can not accomplish this ?

Comment: As far as i know, nope. Whatever behaviour you see is the default behaviour.